# Overlapping UIControls

Tags: ios, touch-event, uicontrol

I have two custom UIControls. These are scrolling wheels.

Their frames overlap. On the screen capture, the one on the top left is behind the one on the right. How may I begin the tracking on the left one when the touch is initiated inside the overlapping region ?

My beginTrackingWithTouch looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (!insideCircle) return NO; } // pseudo-code
```

How can the event be propagated to the views behind the UIControls that respond NO ?

[image: overlapping frames]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is:
1) Subclass UIView for your wheel, for example `WheelView`;
2) Override `-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`
For example:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGFloat xOffset = (point.x - self.bounds.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat yOffset = (point.y - self.bounds.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat distanceSqr = xOffset * xOffset + yOffset * yOffset;
    if (distanceSqr > radius * radius)
    {
        // touch point is outside of circle
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So when you will return `NO`, touch will be propagated to next view, which is "below". This won't however work when your circles will overlap - only when frames, as shown on your screenshot.

Comment: That's OK. The circles are not going to overlap

Comment: @Vrol May I take the time to test it before ?

Comment: Accepting of answers is a good-will decision... Don't force nobody to do this, don't ask about it

Comment: @PetroKorienev Well, some guys here at SO depend on it for their livelihoods. Good-will is just a click away. Why not give it freely, especially when it's helpful? I already upped your answer, by the way.